# Nested combinations – options spread over multiple questions

Tags: ruby, math, combinations

I'm looking at analyzing a test. It consists of four questions with ten options each. From each question, three options must be selected. That of course always yields a total of 12 answers.

Analyzing the number of possible combinations using Ruby's [].combination my Dell Workstations freezes up and fails to produce sane values. Is that calculation really so extremely intense/large?

Using 40 options over 12 answers, I figured I should run:

```
[0...39].combination(12){|x| p x }
```

I also found [the Wikipedia article on Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). But being handicapped in terms of math, it really did not make my any smarter.

I would madly appreciate any help I can get on this matter. Thanks everybody.

**Secondary/follow-up question:**

Plus points to anyone who can figure out a smart way to generate all possible combinations. It's needed for a "offline" Ruby application simulating all possible answers. My brain is dizzy from analyzing the docs – but I cannot seem to find an efficient way to achieve this task.

Ideally, I would need one giant array containing ints representing the options selected:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

...would for example represent a scenario where question one, two, three and four was answered using options 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What sort of information are you trying to get out of the calculation? Is this like an opinion poll or a multiple choice test. You will have 12 options selected but when you look at "combinations" you are calculating how many ways you can select 12 items from the possible 40... and that is quite a few. Actually, it isn't quite as bad as I thought because of the 3 of 10 constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided is asking for all the ways of selecting 12 things from 40 things which is a huge number (hence why your machine freezes), but, from the way you described your situation I don't think that's right.

Each question should be handled separately, that is, you want the number of ways of choosing 3 things from 10 things:

```
[0...9].combination(3) {|x| p x }
```

would print out all the different ways of doing so This gives all the ways of answering a single question (which will be the same for all the questions).

This also should run a lot faster since it's a much smaller calculation.

You then multiply the number of combinations for each question to get the total number of ways of answering all four questions.

My calculation gives:

120 combinations per question.

120 * 120 * 120 * 120 = 207,360,000 combinations for the whole test.

Comment: `40C12` isn't *that* huge (it's `5 586 853 480`), but it's possible it's being computed naively, which *would* cause problems. I do agree with your calculations of the correct answer (`(10C3)^4`), however.

Comment: Spot on dear Sir  :)  You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is four sets of "Choose 3 of 10" combinations.

Please please, oh, please god don't solve this by actually producing all the possible combinations! That's why man invented mathematics :-)

One set of "10 choose three" has a number of options equal to (as shown on the wikipedia page you linked to):

```
10! / ((10-3)! * 3!) 
= 10! / (7! * 3!)
= (10! / 7!) / 3!
= (10 * 9 * 8) / (3 * 2 * 1)
= 720 / 6
= 120
```

You have four of those questions, so you multiply the number of possible combinations in each question to get the total number of combinations for the test.

```
120 * 120 * 120 * 120 
= 207,360,000
```

...just as Jonathan showed, above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but 10 possible answers, choosing 4, would give 210 possibilities.

Then, matching question 1&2 would give 210 * 210 = 44.100 possibilities.
On the other side, matching questions 3&4 would give other 44.100 possibilites.

Matching 1&2 + 3&4 would be **1.944.810.000 possibilites**

That is quite a lot of possibilites...

But your idea of 12 between 40 would give a bigger number, of about **5.586.853.480**.

Usually going *brute-fore* over combinatory is not a good idea...

PS: I'm not sure of the accuracy of my numbers... studied this long time ago

Comment: Jonathan's answer is more accurate (he takes 3 out of 10, while I miread and took 4 out of 10...)